# Looking for different pattern match in app-route

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using the Polymer CLI to create an app.  I am utilizing [Encapsulated Routing with Elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/routing) and [Step 1. Get set up](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up) am trying to match the following patterns:

```
/analyze/:p1

/analyze/:p1/:p2

/analyze/:p1/:p2/:p3
```

That routes to 3 different web components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your [`<app-route>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-route) element, set the following attributes:

- [`pattern`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-route#property-pattern) = your desired route pattern
- [`data`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-route#property-data) = property binding to contain the parsed paths

In your case:

```
<app-route
  pattern="/analyze/:p1/:p2/:p3"
  data="{{routeData}}">
</app-route>
```

`{{routeData}}` will contain:

```
{
  p1: 'a',
  p2: 'b',
  p3: 'c'
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="app-route/app-route.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <app-route
          route="{{route}}"
          pattern="/analyze/:p1/:p2/:p3"
          data="{{routeData}}"
          tail="{{tail}}">
      </app-route>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        ready: function() {
          this.route = {path: "/analyze/a/b/c/d/e/f"};
          console.log('p1', this.routeData.p1);
          console.log('p2', this.routeData.p2);
          console.log('p3', this.routeData.p3);
          console.log('tail', this.tail.path);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vorobot/edit?html,console)</sup>